# Differentiating a function -- e.g., during gradient descent

Tags: gradient-descent, numerics, derivative

To find the gradient of a function such as $y=x^2+2x+1$ at $x=2$, we can do the differentiation symbolically and get $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+2$, which gives a gradient of 6 at $x=2$. If the same process of estimating the gradient at a point is to be done by a computer, my understanding is that the computer uses numerical methods as opposed to symbolic differentiation. Is there any reason why numerical methods are preferred to symbolic differentiation? I know that for a computer to use symbolic differentiation, it only has to parse the expression correctly, determine its form, and then find the result. This should require much less work than numeric differentiation. Thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement even by coding  the derivatives, and exists libraries in many programming languages that can handle symbolic differentiation. When the problem is easily solvable analytically, most times it's indeed the best way to go, but some times you don't have a nice regular manifold to make analytical derivative.

Think about a surface with gaussian noise, and you want to do gradient descent. You can't do the derivative symbolically. Instead you need numerical methods, which could not be faster, but is the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: when I specify a neural network (i.e., a given # of hidden layers, inputs, squashing function, etc), in a tool such as R, Matlab, WEKA-- does the tool use hard coded forms of the derivatives to perform gradient decent? Does it use numerical methods? Or does it formulate the functional form from my inputs and then functionally compute the derivative?  In other-wards, what is the standard way in which methods such as gradient decent are implemented in practice?

Comment: I'm sure they implement the derivatives analytically for every layer to back propagate the errors. In neural networks the non linearity (transfer function) are all derivable. But the derivative is for a given point on the error surface, and not the whole error surface.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that especially for a function of many independent variables, symbolic differentiation is a really bad approach. You should look up reverse mode automatic differentiation. This is a general approach to calculating derivatives. Backpropagation in neural nets is a special case.